# Simulating natural keyboard text entry to html input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing javascript integration tests and I've hit an issue where I cannot reproduce a test case in the tests regarding a user inputting text into a text box.

In this case using something like `$().html()` to change the value doesn't work because it doesn't trigger the underlying actions and the sequence of actions is difficult to trigger explicitly.

Is there a way to simulate keyboard text entry into the input that would cause the actions to trigger naturally?

Comment: What is the test exactly? We may be able to help dependeing on what it is, but if possible I'd extract whatever function you are testing and pass it a string with the text that a user would type

Comment: I would encourage you not to worry about it the bigger problem. I'm curious if there is a way to enter the text in a way that simulates keyboard entry.

Comment: What a toxic environment. Why is this being downvoted? I'm remembering why I don't come on here anymore ....

Comment: We cant help you without knowing how and what you are doing (also not entirely clear what you want) so my downvote is due to lack of information, nothing personal, its not that we are toxic but that the question needs editing in order for us to help. If we cant help, the question wont help people with the same issue and its just using space. Hell, Ill just remove my downvote but I'd advice you edit if you want an answer